# Disable Alphabetic Characters in a Text Field (Part of my code will not execute)

Tags: ios, swift, delegation

To prevent the user from inputting more than one decimal into the text field and to prevent the user from inputting alphabetical characters into the text field I have tried the code below. The problem is I don't know how to check them both within the function and have two If statements which means the second one won't run as it never gets executed. If I take the code that checks number of decimals out and leave the character checker code it works perfectly. How can I get them both working though?

```
 func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let existingTextHasDecimalSeparator = textField.text?.rangeOfString(".")
    let replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator = string.rangeOfString(".")

    let charactersNotAllowed = NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet()
    let replacementTextHasLetter = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(charactersNotAllowed)

    if existingTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil && replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }

    if replacementTextHasLetter != nil {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your function does not work is that it makes its decision early for both the positive and the negative case.

Defer returning `true` to the very end of the function:

```
if existingTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil && replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil {
    // Do not allow multiple decimal separators
    return false
}
if replacementTextHasLetter != nil {
    // Do not allow letters
    return false
}
return true
```

This reflects the all-or-nothing logic of the decision: all checks must succeed in order to all checks, while it takes only one failed check to reject the change.

Comment: Seems obvious now.. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

For swift 4 users you could delete the if replacementTextHasLetter != nil condition thats nested in the first condition along with the else condition and the code would work as well:

```
 let existingTextHasDecimalSeparator = textField.text?.range( of: ".")
 let replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator = string.range( of: ".")

 let charactersNotAllowed = NSCharacterSet.letters
 let replacementTextHasLetter = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: charactersNotAllowed)

 if existingTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil, replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil{
    return false
    } 

 if replacementTextHasLetter != nil{
    return false
}
return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let existingTextHasDecimalSeparator = textField.text?.range( of: ".")
let replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator = string.range( of: ".")

let charactersNotAllowed = NSCharacterSet.letters
let replacementTextHasLetter = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: charactersNotAllowed)

if existingTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil, replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil{
    if replacementTextHasLetter != nil{
        return false
    }
    return false
} else {
    if replacementTextHasLetter != nil{
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Could improve like the one above, but it's how I got my app to not allow multiple decimals and characters. It works.